# web api signalR client

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-web-api2

I have a webapi solution and an .net MVC project. There is a service call that calls an endpoint and throws back a 200 ok. One of the parameters that is passed in this web api project is a return url. This url get invoked after I get a 200 back. This return url goes and calls another endpoint on this webapi solution.

Can I use have a restful web api service endpoint that gets invoked by a service call to call a .net mvc web application signalR? If so how? Do you have examples?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to google "signalr aspnet mvc tutorial"? http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc

Comment: I've gone through hours of videos and tutorials. Alot of them are console applications and the clients are mainly jquery based. So is there such a thing as a web api client for signalR is it possible?